# What is GRefString implementation in GLib?

Tags: c, string, refcounting, ref-struct

I wonder where is the reference count stored? As the type is defined as:

```
typedef char GRefString;
```

And all the `g_ref_string*…()` functions are returning simply `gchar *` instead of a structure, which could hold the reference count. Is it the trick of `sds` library, to hold a metadata header structure right before the `char *` pointed memory? I'm afraid that such implementation can backfire at some point, am I right? I.e.: what problems can arise when using such pre-header equipped strings?

Comment: Answering your questions: if by `sds` you mean `Simple Dynamic Strings` by @antirez than yes: the trick used is the same. The problems that can arise are the usual ones you face when you are using pointers in wrong ways, no more and no less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference counting data is stored before the string.

Following the source code, you'll end up in [g_rc_box_alloc_full()](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/2.66.4/glib/grcbox.c#L170) that has the following relevant line:

```
real_size = private_size + block_size;
```

`block_size` is what you want to allocate in the heap (in the `GRefString` case, the length of the string plus 1) and `private_size` is `sizeof(GArcBox)`, i.e. the struct containing the refcounting data.